# Shall I use Special Characters in Firebase Param Value "event_params.value.string_value" & query in Bigquery?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

In Firebase it is clearly mentioned that "Param values can be up to 100 characters long. The "firebase_", "google_" and "ga_" prefixes are reserved and should not be used."

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Param

But in Google, they did not mention the usage of special characters.

Shall I use special characters like forward slash & Unicode in Firebase Param Value "event_params.value.string_value"?

Will the special characters in Firebase Param Value "event_params.value.string_value" be accepted in Bigquery Table field event_params.value.string_value ?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you referenced clearly specify requirements for parameter's name and value - so obviously you must comply

> Params supply information that contextualize Events. You can associate up to 25 unique Params with each Event type. Some Params are suggested below for certain common Events, but you are not limited to these. You may supply extra Params for suggested Events or custom Params for Custom events. Param names can be up to 40 characters long, may only contain alphanumeric characters and underscores ("*"), and must start with an alphabetic character. Param values can be up to 100 characters long. The "firebase*", "google_" and "ga_" prefixes are reserved and should not be used.

Meantime, those limitations have nothing to do with BigQuery
So, if you are dealing with non-firebase data - feel free to use all those chars

*P.S. the best recommendation I can give for such cases  - try by your own and you will see. It is so easy and fast to get this type of questions answered!*

Comment: Mikhail Sir: Shall i use Forward Splash in Param String Values ""event_params.value.string_value". For Example We are passing

Comment: Mikhail Sir: Shall i use Forward Slash in Param String Values ""event_params.value.string_value". 

For Example We are passing  Special characters in firebase_screen Key Values. 

String Value without special characters for example "Productscreen" key value Bigquery count matches with Google analytics count, 

But the product/viewprofilescreen (That contains special character (/) bigquery count is much less than the Google analytics count. 

That is the reason i am asking this question. PLs. find below the quer for your kind reference. Pls. Help Sir

Comment: select event_date,event_name, 

param.value.string_value as firebase_screen,count(*) as screen_views
From <table>,
UNNEST (event_params) as param
where event_name = 'screen_view' and param.key='firebase_screen'group by 1,2,3 order by screen_views desc