# Can I use non-english letters in Firebase Analytics events?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I have some logging in Firebase like this:

```
    fun log(action: String, category: Category, label: Label, value: Int) {
        firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(
            label.tag,
            bundleOf(
                "category" to category.tag,
                "action" to action,
                FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE to value
            )
        )
    }
```

Can I use non-english words, such as "Экран_авторизации" instead of "registration_screen" in my bundle parametres?

**Update**

As it turned out, we can use cyrillic alphabet WITHOUT spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase documentation lists the [requirements for names of custom events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event) as:

> Event names can be up to 40 characters long, may only contain [alphanumeric characters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetterOrDigit-int-) and underscores ("*"), and must start with an [alphabetic character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter-int-). The "firebase*", "google_" and "ga_" prefixes are reserved and should not be used.

There's also a list of reserved names in this documentation, so be sure to check that out.

Aside from that, you can use any Unicode characters in Analytics event names, parameter names, and values.

Also see:

- [Shall I use Special Characters in Firebase Param Value "event_params.value.string_value" & query in Bigquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53411760/shall-i-use-special-characters-in-firebase-param-value-event-params-value-strin) (for parameter names)